# Windows API Error "The handle is invalid"

Tags: go, winapi

I'm trying to create a program that utilises the `MiniDumpWriteDump` Windows API to dump another process's memory. However, it keeps returning an error saying `The handle is invalid`. I'm pretty confident in my process handle because I've used the `OpenProcess` Windows API before, so I think it's how I'm using `CreateFileW`.

I have looked at examples online like [this one](https://play.golang.org/p/v2EAG6YwRK) but I can't get anything working.

Here is my code so far:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strconv"
    "syscall"
    "unsafe"
)

var kernel32        = syscall.NewLazyDLL("kernel32.dll")
var procOpenProcess = kernel32.NewProc("OpenProcess")
var procCreateFileW = kernel32.NewProc("CreateFileW")
var procCloseHandle = kernel32.NewProc("CloseHandle")

var dbghelp               = syscall.NewLazyDLL("Dbghelp.dll")
var procMiniDumpWriteDump = dbghelp.NewProc("MiniDumpWriteDump")

func main() {
    fmt.Println("[ ] Starting Enum-DumpProcessMemory\n")

    pid, _ := strconv.Atoi(os.Args[1])
    fmt.Println("[-] PID            :", pid)

    processHandle, _, _ := procOpenProcess.Call(uintptr(0xFFFF), uintptr(1), uintptr(pid))
    fmt.Println("[-] Process Handle :", processHandle)

    path, _ := syscall.UTF16PtrFromString(os.Args[2])
    fileHandle, _, _ := procCreateFileW.Call(uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(path)), syscall.GENERIC_READ, syscall.FILE_SHARE_READ|syscall.FILE_SHARE_WRITE, 0, syscall.OPEN_EXISTING, syscall.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0)
    fmt.Println("[-] File Handle    :", fileHandle)

    ret, _, err := procMiniDumpWriteDump.Call(uintptr(processHandle), uintptr(pid), uintptr(fileHandle), 0x00061907, 0, 0, 0)

    if ret != 0 {
        fmt.Println("[+] Process memory dump successful")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("[x] Process memory dump not successful")
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
}
```

Here is the output:

```
> .\Enum-DumpProcessMemory.exe 6892 C:\Users\user\Documents\dump.dmp
[ ] Starting Enum-DumpProcessMemory

[-] PID            : 6892
[-] Process Handle : 236
[-] File Handle    : 18446744073709551615
[x] Process memory dump not successful
The handle is invalid.
```

Comment: Which handle is invalid? What function is failing? What error code does `GetLastError()` return?

Comment: It doesn't say which error is invalid, however, I think it's the file handle. The `MiniDumpWriteDump` process is failing. `GetLastError()` returns `0`.

Comment: The way to find out which handle is invalid is to check for errors.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I did a little more debugging and realised my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the code working thanks to the help from Jonathan Potter. The problem was that I was trying to create a handler to a file that didn't exist.

Here is my working code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strconv"
    "syscall"
    "unsafe"
)

var kernel32        = syscall.NewLazyDLL("kernel32.dll")
var procOpenProcess = kernel32.NewProc("OpenProcess")
var procCreateFileW = kernel32.NewProc("CreateFileW")

var dbghelp               = syscall.NewLazyDLL("Dbghelp.dll")
var procMiniDumpWriteDump = dbghelp.NewProc("MiniDumpWriteDump")

func main() {
    fmt.Println("[ ] Starting Enum-DumpProcessMemory\n")

    pid, _ := strconv.Atoi(os.Args[1])
    fmt.Println("[-] PID            :", pid)

    processHandle, _, _ := procOpenProcess.Call(uintptr(0xFFFF), uintptr(1), uintptr(pid))
    fmt.Println("[-] Process Handle :", processHandle)

    if _, err := os.Stat(os.Args[2]); os.IsNotExist(err) {
        os.Create(os.Args[2])
    }
    path, _ := syscall.UTF16PtrFromString(os.Args[2])

    fileHandle, _, _ := procCreateFileW.Call(uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(path)), syscall.GENERIC_WRITE, syscall.FILE_SHARE_READ|syscall.FILE_SHARE_WRITE, 0, syscall.OPEN_EXISTING, syscall.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0)
    fmt.Println("[-] File Handle    :", fileHandle)

    ret, _, err := procMiniDumpWriteDump.Call(uintptr(processHandle), uintptr(pid), uintptr(fileHandle), 0x00061907, 0, 0, 0)

    if ret != 0 {
        fmt.Println("[+] Process memory dump successful")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("[x] Process memory dump not successful")
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
}
```